# Display difference between two locations on plot

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I've been trying to display the difference in y between a point and a line. This code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[title={title},xlabel={x},ylabel={y},xmajorgrids=true,ymajorgrids=true,scaled y ticks=false,y tick label style={/pgf/number format/fixed},ymin=355,xtick=data]
            \addplot[mark=*,thick,black] coordinates{(1,433.6)(2,425.2)}
                coordinate [pos=0] (start)
                coordinate [pos=1] (end);
            \coordinate (line) at (axis cs:1,365.2);
            \draw[red,dashed] (line) -- (line -| end);
            \draw[<->,dashed,shorten <=3pt]
                let \p1=(line), 
                    \p2=(end), 
                    \n1={\y2-\y1} in
                    (end) -- node[anchor=east]{\pgfplotsconvertunittocoordinate{y}{\n1}\pgfplotscoordmath{y}{datascaletrafo inverse to fixed}{\pgfmathresult}\pgfmathprintnumber[fixed,precision=1]{\pgfmathresult}} (line -| end);
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

resulted in

[image: mwe]

and displays 415 instead of 60. This isn't due to some kind of LaTeX math inaccuracy, right? Am I doing something wrong with the scaling?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't find the commands you are using in the manual, but a rather standard trick is to take the ratio of the unknown distance and a known distance to figure out what the distance in axis units is. So I divide the distance between the symbolic points by the known distance between (say) `(axis cs:0,430)` and `(axis cs:0,330)` and then know what the distance in axis units is.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[title={title},xlabel={x},ylabel={y},xmajorgrids=true,ymajorgrids=true,scaled y ticks=false,y tick label style={/pgf/number format/fixed},ymin=355,xtick=data]
            \addplot[mark=*,thick,black] coordinates{(1,433.6)(2,425.2)}
                coordinate [pos=0] (start)
                coordinate [pos=1] (end);
            \coordinate (line) at (axis cs:1,365.2);
            \draw[red,dashed] (line) -- (line -| end);
            \draw[<->,dashed,shorten <=3pt]
                let \p1=(line), 
                    \p2=(end), 
                    \p3=($(axis cs:0,430)-(axis cs:0,330)$),
                    \n1={100*(\y2-\y1)/\y3} in
                    (end) -- node[anchor=east]{\pgfmathparse{\n1}%
                    \pgfmathprintnumber[fixed,precision=1]{\pgfmathresult}
                    } (line -| end);
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Can't see right now how this adds up, but it seems subtracting `ymin` gives you the correct value. I.e. add `\pgfmathparse{\pgfmathresult-\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymin}}` before the `\pgfmathprintnumber`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[title=title,xlabel={x},ylabel={y},xmajorgrids=true,ymajorgrids=true,scaled y ticks=false,y tick label style={/pgf/number format/fixed},ymin=355,xtick=data]
            \addplot[mark=*,thick,black] coordinates{(1,433.6)(2,425.2)}
                coordinate [pos=0] (start)
                coordinate [pos=1] (end);
            \coordinate (line) at (axis cs:1,365.2);
            \draw[red,dashed] (line) -- (line -| end);
            \draw[<->,dashed,shorten <=3pt]
                let \p1=(line), 
                    \p2=(end), 
                    \n1={\y2-\y1} in
                    (end) -- node[anchor=east]{\pgfplotsconvertunittocoordinate{y}{\n1}\pgfplotscoordmath{y}{datascaletrafo inverse to fixed}{\pgfmathresult}\pgfmathparse{\pgfmathresult-\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymin}}\pgfmathprintnumber[fixed,precision=1]{\pgfmathresult}} (line -| end);
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 for the sweet happenstance, but unfortunately in my actual plot, the dashed line does not correspond with `ymin` - perhaps my MWE was a bit too minimal.